# How to Configure Microsoft.office.interop to server's Microsoft Office..?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, pdf, ms-word

i have to convert a word doc into pdf and print it and `Microsoft.Office.interop` offers an easy way to do it but client machine has be installed with 2013 or higher.
My question is. is there any way that i could convert the word file into pdf using Server's Microsoft office because i can't expect client have 2013 installed on their pc

if no is there any easy and free way to convert word file into pdf.?

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Word Automation Services (part of SharePoint) can convert Word documents to PDF (and other file formats) in the server environment.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use Office Interop on server. 
You can use OpenXML for working with office docs. 
There are many examples available here.
For conversion, you will have to use separate plugin, and I'm not aware of a free version to convert to PDF.